# Bash script with data from another file

Tags: linux, bash

I have worked on the following script which I want to use to easily add multiple Postfix as well as a few other things.

Below is a small sample

```
postmulti -e init
postmulti -I postfix-$new -e create
cd /etc/postfix-$new
rm -rf main.cf
wget http://www.********.com/*******/main.zip
unzip main.zip
mv main main.cf
echo -e "queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$new" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
echo -e "data_directory = /var/lib/postfix-$new" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
echo -e "multi_instance_name = postfix-$new" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
echo -e "mydomain = $domain" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
echo -e "myhostname = host1.$domain" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
echo -e "smtp_bind_address = $ip" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
sed -i "s/oldip/$ip/g" /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf

mv /etc/opendkim/keys/$domain/default.private /etc/opendkim/keys/$domain/default
echo -e "/ndefault._domainkey.$domain $domain:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/$domain/default" >> /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
echo -e "/n*@$domain default._domainkey.$domain" >> /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
sed -i "s/cyberciti.com/$domain/g" /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
```

There are three requirements for this script `$new` `$ip` `$domain` I want to know how I can add them into a file line by line and then bash this script, one line = one full run of the script.

For example `start` contains

```
new1, 1.1.1.1, myweb.com
new2, 2.2.2.2, myweb2.com
```

The first line should run the following

```
postmulti -e init
 postmulti -I postfix-new1 -e create
 cd /etc/postfix-new1
 rm -rf main.cf
 wget http://www.********.com/*******/main.zip
 unzip main.zip
 mv main main.cf
 echo -e "queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-new1" >> /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf
 echo -e "data_directory = /var/lib/postfix-new1" >> /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf
 echo -e "multi_instance_name = postfix-new1" >> /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf
 echo -e "mydomain = myweb.com" >> /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf
 echo -e "myhostname = host1.myweb.com" >> /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf
 echo -e "smtp_bind_address = 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf
 sed -i "s/oldip/1.1.1.1/g" /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf

 mv /etc/opendkim/keys/myweb.com/default.private /etc/opendkim/keys/myweb.com/default
 echo -e "/ndefault._domainkey.myweb.com myweb.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/myweb.com/default" >> /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
 echo -e "/n*@myweb.com default._domainkey.myweb.com" >> /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
sed -i "s/cyberciti.com/$myweb.com/g" /etc/postfix-new1/main.cf
```

and so on until all lines in the `start` file are complete

Comment: If your "start" file can be made space-delimited, you could just wrap your existing script with: while read new ip domain; do ... existing script ... done < start

Comment: Yes it can be spaced rather than comma, anything really. How can I do that? Can you post the answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would replace your script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read new ip domain
do
  postmulti -e init
  postmulti -I postfix-$new -e create
  cd /etc/postfix-$new
  rm -rf main.cf
  wget http://www.********.com/*******/main.zip
  unzip main.zip
  mv main main.cf
  echo -e "queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$new" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
  echo -e "data_directory = /var/lib/postfix-$new" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
  echo -e "multi_instance_name = postfix-$new" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
  echo -e "mydomain = $domain" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
  echo -e "myhostname = host1.$domain" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
  echo -e "smtp_bind_address = $ip" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
  sed -i "s/oldip/$ip/g" /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf

  mv /etc/opendkim/keys/$domain/default.private /etc/opendkim/keys/$domain/default
  echo -e "/ndefault._domainkey.$domain $domain:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/$domain/default" >> /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
  echo -e "/n*@$domain default._domainkey.$domain" >> /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
  sed -i "s/cyberciti.com/$domain/g" /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf

done < start.txt
```

... all I did was wrap a `while` loop around your existing code.

If I can suggest one other minor change, it would be to consolidate all of your `echo` statements into one "here" document, like this:

```
cat >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf << EOF
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$new
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix-$new
...
EOF
```

If not for performance reasons (you may not care), but because it's easier to read.

Comment: This code works under the assumption from the original comments that the input `start.txt` file is space-separated.

Comment: Thank you this works! The only problem is with "echo 'abuse@$domain   abuse@myhost.com' >> /etc/postfix/virtual" - That prints as abuse@$domain rather than the domain. Would doing what you suggested above (consolidate all of your echo statements) fix this?

Comment: The single quote marks prevent variable expansion, so change them to double quotes or remove them altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
while read line;
do
new1=$(echo $line | cut -d"," -f1)
ip=$(echo $line | cut -d"," -f2)
domain=$(echo $line | cut -d"," -f3)
<Your bash script here with above three variables>
done < file.txt
```

Comment: file.txt should contain "new1, 1.1.1.1, myweb.com" ?

Comment: Not necessary.. As long as the ip, domain and new1 field are separated by comma, any data can be used. But, be certain that no comma should appear other than those three.

Comment: This didn't work for me